# Using next.config.js in nextjs typescript for custom configuration

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sass, next.js

I am new to nextjs typescript, and I am trying to use next.config.js in nextjs typescript for my custom configurations such as

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  sassOptions: {
    includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, 'styles')],
  },
}
```

I have created a next.config.js file next to my package.json but the next.config.js is seen not to work, I have gone through [this documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/introduction) and I encountered a quote

> Avoid using new JavaScript features not available in your target
> Node.js version. next.config.js will not be parsed by Webpack, Babel
> , or TypeScript.

Which I don't understand.
My major question is how will I use next.config.js in my nextjs typescript project?
Any suggestion will be highly welcome. Thanks

Comment: your config looks ok , try to upgrade your node js version, if you are using nvm you can just do `nvm install node`

Comment: maybe that option is not valid anymore in newest next.js

Comment: _"the next.config.js is seen not to work"_ - what makes you think that's the case? Have you tried adding other options to the config file to check if those work as intended?

Comment: @juliomalves I do, my bad I forget to run npm install --save-dev sass in my case as I do, I problem solved Thank you. I really don't know if it was the cause but the important thing is my problem solved

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the quote is that `next.config.js` is loaded before any of the additional tools like webpack or typescript come into the picture. The reason for this should be obvious: Your `next.config.js` file may have settings for webpack or typescript, so it *must* be loaded before those tools are loaded to build your app.